# How do I change the animation of a clicked button in css?

Tags: css, button

When a button that is not styled by any css is clicked, it turns blue for an instant and then returns to its normal white color.

However, when a button that is styled as shown below is clicked, a blue highlight appears around it and does not go away until something else on the screen is clicked.

I would like my button not to have this weird blue highlight. How would I fix this and still keep the button styled?

Any solutions I have found thus far involve javascript, but I am looking for a pure css solution here.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

  button {
      border: solid #316A8F;
      border-radius: 12px;
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
      color: #003C63;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<button>click me.</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `focus` try this:

```
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```css
button {
      border: solid #316A8F;
      border-radius: 12px;
      background-color: #F9F9F9;
      color: #003C63;
  }
  
  button:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
```

```html
<button>click me.</button>
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it 'answered' so it may help others in the future. Thanks!